# Fail2ban don't want to start the server

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

I just installed fail2ban on my Ubuntu 10.04 server.

When I try to start the client it returns:

> ERROR  Could not start server. Maybe an old socket file is still present. Try to remove /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock. If you used fail2ban-client to start the server, adding the -x option will do it

I deleted the fail2ban.sock, but nothing changed. How should I fix this?

Comment: How do you try to start the client?

Comment: fail2ban-client start

Comment: Anything in `fail2ban.log`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess your fail2ban server closed unexpectedly (may be killed?). Check `/var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock` file. Remove if exist and run fail2ban with command below:

`sudo service fail2ban start`

**OR**

`sudo systemctl start fail2ban.service`

**OR ELSE**

`sudo fail2ban-client start`

considering to which is supported with OS you are using.

Also you may try to run another instance of fail2ban. Before you run fail2ban, check for service with `ps ax | grep fail2ban`. If service is not running, then you can safely start service.

Comment: Thx ! I started it with sudo fail2ban-client start as i see on the Ubuntu french documentation and it didn't works... Now it seems to works well.
I'll ask for a change of the french wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into this same error today, and I found out the /var/run/fail2ban folder was missing from my CentOS 8 server.

I manually re-created this folder by

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/fail2ban
```

And rebooted the fail2ban service successfully.

BTW, I did forcefully rebooted this VPS from a Cloud service vendor's web-based control panel. It seems that this reboot caused the missing folder.